# Why do quote marks appear in output when saved with Save Selection As?

Tags: front-end, export, output-formatting, image

***Update #2:*** This behavior has been confirm across platforms and in multiple versions.  Therefore:

1. Is this a bug or a feature?
2. Can I disable this "feature" so that copying a selection of Cell contents works the same as copying the entire Cell?

---

*Update:* As Simon Woods astutely observed this problem only occurs when you select the cell *contents* rather than the entire cell via the bracket.  Those two tested this and reported, please check again selecting only the contents and see if the behavior appears.

---

In version 10 quote marks (i.e. [`ShowStringCharacters`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ShowStringCharacters.html)) appear in output when it is saved as an image using **Save Selection As...**:

```
CharacterRange["a", "z"]
```

Appearance in the Notebook:

> {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z}

When saved as a PNG:

[image]

These quote marks do not appear in export from version 7, at least as I had it configured.

#### Why do they appear?

#### Can I keep them from appearing?

Comment: I do not have MMA 10 installed yet... but I would like to know whether you have tried to **Save Selection As...** of `ToExpression[CharacterRange["a", "z"]]` ?

Comment: @Boson I haven't tried that, but that's not really what this question is about.  Your code would produce Symbols rather than Strings.

Comment: Am not seeing this on OS X

Comment: Strange. I get the quotes if I select the cell *contents* but not if I select the cell bracket.

Comment: I'm on Windows 8.1 and my behavior is exactly as @SimonWoods reports.

Comment: @Simon I confirm that behavior as well.  Thanks for being thorough.  I should have checked that myself.

Comment: Here is my summary: First of all, I _do not_ get any quotes when exporting to pdf. I _do_ get quotes if I select the cell contents and use **Save Selection As..** to save to png. I _do not_ get quotes if I either select the whole cell to **Save Selection As** png or use `Export["quotes.png", CharacterRange["a", "z"]]`.

Comment: Yes I am now seeing this on OS X when I select the contents rather than the cell bracket. Furthermore this"feature" was introduced in V9. In V8 selecting cell contents and saving as PNG did not produce string quotes. In V9 it does.

Answer (score 4):

The quotes appear because the InputForm does not show them, while the OutputForm does.

Programmatically, you can explicitly call OutputForm to avoid this:

```
Export["quotes.png", OutputForm[CharacterRange["a", "z"]]]
```

[image]

You can also go into Format > Option inspector… and look for ShowStringCharacters and using Save selection as…:

[image]

Comment: Carlo, would you please describe exactly what you changed in the Option Inspector?  I cannot seem to find the right setting for this.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Funny, I can't reproduce the behavior you described under Linux. I think the option mentioned by Carlo is under FormattingOptions>ExpressionFormatting>DisplayOptions. For me it does not change the behavior of the string export, however.

Comment: As a matter of fact I've changed the option back, and I still can't see the quotes, but I'm on MacOs X in this case this might be a bug specific to Linux.

Comment: @sebhofer I'm on Windows so if this is not happening in either OSX or Linux I think it is a bug.

Answer (score 4):

*1. Is this a bug or a feature?*

My opinion is that it is not a bug.  Different selections yield different inputs, so different outputs are at least possible.  On the other hand, I'm not sure I would call it a feature.  It strikes me that users will wonder why they cannot easily get an image of what they see.

"Save Selection As..." seems to consistently show the results of `NotebookRead[]`.  There are (at least) three forms of output from `NotebookRead[]`, a box expression, a complete `Cell` or a list of cells, or a `String`.  Each type is packaged into a `Notebook` that is then exported.

Examples of the three forms are shown below.  The first is the selection of the contents of the output cell of `CharacterRange["a", "c"]`.  The second is the selection of the whole output cell.  The third is the selection of the number `123` in an input cell.

Note that a box expression is put in a cell with no style.  A complete `Cell` is passed as is.  And note that a `String`, such as `123`, is automatically formatted as `"Text"`.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In this regard, [@Carlo](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/18576/carlo) has it right, that when only the contents are selected, we lose the information that the style is `"Output"`.

It is not clear to me why, assuming it is intentional, saving a selection from the contents of the cell does not automatically inherit the cell style of the enclosing cell in the notebook expression that is exported.  There could be issues if the selection was inside a inline cell I suppose.  For instance sometimes *Mathematca* interprets actions, such as when an input or output cell is pasted inside an input cell.  The expression is pasted, not the cell, whereas pasting a text cell in an input cell yields an inline cell.

*2. Workaround?*

I don't have a general solution.   One might add something to KeyEventTranslations.tr or to MenuSetup.tr to select the cell.  If `nb` is the notebook with the selection to be saved, the following

```
SelectionMove[nb, All, Cell];
FrontEndTokenExecute[nb, "SelectionSaveSpecial"]
```

Other programmatic approaches seem possible, such as styling the selection with the cell's style.  I could not discover a way so that the menu command would do this.

Answer (score 2):

With V10 on OS X, I get

[image: png]

Might be a platform issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on `10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 29, 2014)` and and have the following observed:

- highlighting the Output-Cell and using the Command "Save Selection As" leads to the following result;

[image]

[image]

- highlighting the Output and using the Command "Save Selection As" leads to the observed result;

[image]

[image]

Wile

```
CellPrint[ExpressionCell[CharacterRange["a", "z"], "Output", ShowStringCharacters -> True]]
```

outputs

> {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", 
>   "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"}

does

```
CellPrint[ExpressionCell[CharacterRange["a", "z"], "Output", ShowStringCharacters -> False]]
```

what one shall expect:

> {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z}

at least on the Monitor ... Standing above can be applied accordingly for "Save Selection As"

Comment: This also happens in V9 ...but not in V8.