# Save as pdf broken in version 10.0.2?

Tags: plotting, bugs, pdf-format

**Fixed in 10.1**

---

It looks like the save as pdf is broken after I update to version 10.0.2. The labels in the plot become a mess.

Are there ways to fix it? The `Export` function works well though.

Here is a screenshot

[image]

[image]
I'm using OS X 10.10.1 (14B25)

**update**

It seems to be a frontend problem. Now I'm using a 10.0.2 kernel with a 10.0.1 frontend, which works great for me.

Comment: Can't reproduce this. I have 10.0.2 with OS X 10.10.1

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Thanks for testing. What mac are you using? I'm using a 2011 year Macbook air.

Comment: @xslittlegrass Can confirm this on Ubuntu 14.04 with Mathematica V10.0.2

Comment: Unlike @Mike I see this problem with 10.0.2 with OS X 10.10.1 (MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014)). A workaround is to use Preview to take a screenshot from selection then Save... with Format set to PDF.

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks for confirming but the screenshot has a very low resolution.

Comment: On Windows 7 and 10.0.2 : with `Save Selection As` I get garbage even for text, with `Save As` all is fine.

Comment: I can confirm this, 10.0.2, OS X 10.10.1.

Comment: This is not the only issue with Save As..., there's also [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38745/12).  So it's probably better to use `Export` anyway.

Comment: @Szabolcs `Export` works great, but what I really miss is the copying feature. Since the save as is broken, the copied image is also broken.

Comment: @Szabolcs I'm posting this to the wolfram community, hoping to get their attention and maybe fixed soon. The Technical support seems doesn't have the power to push the bug get fixed. I have reported many to them, but only a few get fixed.

Comment: The good news is that there's already a sign that a 10.0.3 might be coming.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks for the news, I'm feeling better now :)

Comment: 10.0.2 under Windows: context-menu item broken as illustrated, but **File** > **Save Selection As...** still works correctly.

Comment: Possibly related: [(55435)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55435/121)

Comment: Thats weird that others with similar set ups to me are seeing different. I have a 14 month old mac mini

Comment: @halirutan A bit embarrassed to ask, but how on earth do I update my 10.0.0.0 to a more recent version. My pref. is set to automatic update.

Comment: @MathLind The update of Mathematica itself will not happen automatically. I'm not sure if everyone can get the minor updates (like 10.0.1->10.0.2) for free, but you should be able to find out by logging into the [Wolfram user portal](user.wolfram.com). There, I can manage all my licenses, get the new versions, etc..

Comment: back at my computer now and I must be going crazy. Save As and Copy As give the same result as above. However Print As, then save to PDF, works fine. Maybe that was what I did but I don't remember doing it that way!

Comment: I confirm this with 10.0.2 on Mac OSX 10.9.5.Save selection as PDF is definitely broken. Export to PDF works.

Comment: @halirutan Thank you for the feedback. Good news: As from yesterday, the update 10.0.2 seems to be available even for hobbyists.

Comment: This is a pretty amusing glitch.

Comment: Have you received any responses about this from support?

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes/No. I checked my email again, and remembered that the technical support send me an empty message. I was in a meeting and meant to ask them but forgot. I sent a message to ask them just now. I will put their answer here after hearing back from them. Thanks for the reminder. By the way the case number is [CASE:1993278].

Comment: response from technical support: "Our development team has been made aware of this issue and are looking into it."

Comment: I just ran into this problem with Mathematica 10.0.2 on  Mac OS 10.9.5.  I'm fairly sure it only started happening when I upgraded to Mathematica 10.0.2, so I restored 10.0.1 from a Time Machine backup, and the problem no longer appears. So from what I see, it is a new problem introduced in 10.0.2, despite what SquareOne reported.

Comment: Maybe using "Save Selection As..." could be a solution for the moment. BTW, it seems that when the graphics are 3D, the font changing does not occur.

Comment: Cannot reproduce this with *Mathematica* 10.1 under OS X 10.10.3.

Answer (score 2):

Downgrade from Mathematica 10.0.2 back to 10.0.1.  This can be done using a Time Machine backup if you have one on Mac OS.  That fixed it for me, and there is nothing particular in 10.0.2 that I need, as far as I know.

Comment: "Downgrade from Mathematica 10.0.2 back to 10.0.1." <- The OP already knew that the bug was introduced in 10.0.2.  "and there is nothing particular in 10.0.2 that I need" <- Except lots of fixes to other bugs which may or may not be as disruptive as this one, including bugs which cause silent wrong results.  *Point releases are primarily for bugfixes and I wouldn't advise to anyone to downgrade.*  If something like this is particularly disruptive, it's always possible to keep 10.0.1 and 10.0.2 side by side.

Comment: I do agree though that this is extremely disruptive when one needs to produce figures.

Comment: You are right, i checked again, no problem with 10.0.1 (OSX10.9.5), only with 10.0.2. By the way, I have v9.0, v10.0.1, v10.0.2 installed side by side. To install your v10.0.1 side by side with your already installed v10.0.2, you just have to give it a different name, that's all.

Comment: Szabolcs: There were no answers to the question, so I thought I would add a non-ideal one so that new readers didn't have to delve through all the comments. Each person should decide for themselves whether to downgrade or not; for me, it is a serious impediment to my workflow, as I am frequently copying plots into emails to send to people. I have to balance this against a set of unknown bug fixes (is there an actual list somewhere?) which may potentially avoid silent wrong results. It's easier to use Export than to switch versions when I need to copy a plot, both of which are disruptive.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround for Mathematica 10.0.2:

Save twice!

The second one will be normal.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work, but I had a styling issue that was helped with:
[Awful styling in MMA10's Plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/70215/awful-styling-in-mma10s-plot)