# Font rendering difference between .jpg & .pdf

Tags: graphics, export, bugs

I have some planar graphics involving lines and text, produced by `Line[]` and `Text[]`, accepting the default font on the latter.
When I Save Graphics as **.jpg**, it looks fine, left below.
When I save as **.pdf**, the fonts are mangled, right below.

---

[image: JPGvsPDF]

---

This is using Mathematica 10.0.2.0 running under Mac OSX 10.9.5.
Has anyone encountered this problem before?

---

Below, `pts1` and `pts2` are 2D points list:

```
n = Length[pts1];
text1 = MapThread[Text[#1, #2] &, {Range[1, n], pts1}];
text2 = MapThread[Text[#1, #2] &, {Range[1, n], pts2}];
g = Graphics[{
    Purple, Line[pts1], Red, text1,
    Green, Line[pts2], text2
    }]
```

I exported by right-clicking on the notebook image and selecting `Save Graphics As...`

Comment: Confirmed for 10.0.2 on Win7 64. It *does* work with `Export["x.pdf"]` though.

Comment: Related (essentially a dupe, but no answer): http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/68893/131

Comment: @YvesKlett: Excellent---Thanks! I will simply use `Export[]` from now on (even though right-clicking is certainly more convenient).

Comment: Joseph, for reproduction and documentation purposes I find `Export` much more convenient (depending on how repetitive a given task is). Plus, you have full control over the options.

Comment: @Yves Shall we close this as a duplicate?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I´d say yes (probably takes a mod to close here, as the other question does not have an answer as well).