# Saving a plot as a pdf to use in Latex

Tags: differential-equations, latex

I use the following code:

```
sol = DSolveValue[{y'[t] == 1/(2 y[t] + 3), y[0] == 1}, y, t];
Plot[sol[t], {t, -10, 10}, ImageSize -> Small]
```

Then I Ctrl+click the image (Macbook Pro) and save the image as test.pdf.

Then, in the same folder, I write the following latex code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{test.pdf}
\end{document}
```

I compile using pdflatex and I get the following image.

[image]

Is this a bug?

Comment: Can you include what Mma version and OS you are using. There are some known problems with PDFs in V10

Comment: Very closely related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/68893/131

Comment: I am using Mathematica 10.0.2, macbook pro Yosemite 8.0.2, machete texlive 2014. I Ctrl+clicked the image in my notebook, selected Save Graphic As..., then selected PDF from the format list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug related to exporting via the context menu. 
Try exporting using:

```
sol = DSolveValue[{y'[t] == 1/(2 y[t] + 3), y[0] == 1}, y, t];
p = Plot[sol[t], {t, -10, 10}, ImageSize -> Small]
Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "test.pdf", p, "PDF"]
```

Comment: I would recommend Export[NotebookDirectory[]<>"test.pdf",p, "PDF"].

Comment: Yes you are right. Relying on Mathematica to infer the export format might not be a great idea.

Comment: This worked for me, so I do think we have discovered a bug.

Answer (score 0):

In generally, I used the method as below:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}]
```

Select the output cell ->  Save selected as -> sample.pdf

> [image]

```
\documentclass[b5paper,UTF8]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}                               
\begin{document}
\texttt{Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}]}

 \vspace{1mm}
 \fbox{\includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{sample.pdf}}
 \vspace{1mm}
\end{document}
```

> [image]