# Export graphic as Pdf gives incorrect font size

Tags: plotting, export, pdf-format

In Mathematica 10.0.2 I have this plot:

[image]

Now, when I export as pdf, I have these huge fonts. Any workaround?

[image]

Comment: Shall I close this as a duplicate of [(68893)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/68893/121)?

Comment: Feel free to close. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I was too lazy to look a little more at the similar questions. The answer is to use Export which is not broken.