# Mathematica 10.4.1 broken fonts when saving as PDF

Tags: export, pdf-format, fonts

I am using Mathematica 10.4.1 in Linux and have spotted the following uncomfortable behavior. When saving a notebook as a PDF file, some fonts are not properly displayed (see attached figure below, where the right-hand side displays the notebook and the left-hand side the exported PDF).

My issue is not quite that of [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/68893/save-as-pdf-broken-in-version-10-0-2), and the solutions given there (downgrade) are not explorable (I only have a Home License for my current version).

The funny thing is, though, that if I set FontFamily to some undefined value, then the image is exported all right (the input/output cell indicators are still not correctly shown in the PDF).

[image: Depiction of the unfortunate behavior.]

Also, here is what xset -q   returns:

```
Font Path: /usr/share/fonts/Type1/,/usr/share/fonts/misc/,/usr/share/fonts/TTF/,/usr/share/fonts/OTF/,/usr/share/fonts/Type1/,/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/,/usr/share/fonts/75dpi/,built-ins
```

Apparently Type1 fonts are first looked for, as suggested [in the Mathematica docu](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FontsOnLinux.html).

Thank you very much in advance for any hint you may give!

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem...

Comment: It seems that those fonts that look blocky are the Type 3 fonts...

Comment: Installing Helvetica did solve this same issue. Check this related question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/123863/mathematica-versions-10-and-11-fonts-are-broken-on-linux/