# Mathematica versions 10 and 11 fonts are broken on Linux

Tags: notebooks, kernel, fonts

Any clues on how to fix the fonts? It seems the font kerning is wrong. It happens both in graphics and in all sorts of text styles...

This happens with Mathematica system fonts but also with certain styles in graphics. Moreover, when I select with the mouse cursor the affected text, the selected text does jerky movements with glyphs moving on top of neighbouring glyphs.

This issue seems to be related to this: [Mathematica 10.4.1 broken fonts when saving as PDF](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115022/mathematica-10-4-1-broken-fonts-when-saving-as-pdf?rq=1)

Please look at the snapshots below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't observe this with Mathematica 11.0 and Ubuntu 16.04. Some specific problem with your font setup, perhaps?

Comment: @MichaelLee: any idea on how to check which font is being used?

Comment: It might be useful to say which distribution you are using.

Comment: my linux: Archlinux 4.5.4-1-ARCH. Using i3 as window manager.

Comment: There's probably something wrong with the configuration. Have you tried resetting your installation's configuration to it's default values:
http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12464

Comment: Yes, I just tried that, to no avail. Also, I have Mathematica locally installed. Could it be that somehow there are hard coded paths to /usr/share/Mathematica?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I managed to narrow down the problem to the font Helvetica. It seems Mathematica was relying on my system having Helvetica already installed, which I did not.

After installing a package for Arch Linux, namely https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ephifonts/, which includes the font Helvetica, I now get the previous snapshots looking like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It would be nice if someone could replicate this by removing Helvetica from his/her system and check if he/she gets the same issues as I did.