# Mathematica 11 fonts in Linux are messed up

Tags: fonts, linux, version-11, unicode

> This is not a duplicate of [Mathematica versions 10 and 11 fonts are broken on Linux](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/123863).  There the issue is with PDF export and printing.

The fonts in Mathematica on my system are all messed up, see the Screenshots below.  I think I have installed the `mathematica-fonts` packages on my Debian GNU/Linux stable system but this did not resolve it.

It seems as if the only subset working properly is ASCII.

A websearch brought up a thread on the Arch Linux forum: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=184112

The suggestion there is to disable antialiasing for fonts in the KDE control center and removing `~/.config/Trolltech.conf`.  I didn't have the KDE control center (I don't use KDE) so I installed it and followed the steps but to no avail.

### Some random documentation page

[image]

### The Basic Math Assistant

[image]

### Even the splash screen is broken (next to »Open«)

[image]

Comment: I don't have this problem with MMA 11 and Ubuntu 15.10. I just installed it normally and that's it. What's your distribution?

Comment: @anderstood As mentioned in the question it is Debian GNU/Linux stable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and solved it by removing the configuration file associated with emojione-color. The font's substitution mechanism seemed to interfere with Mathematica's.

Just fyi, the file I removed was /etc/fonts/conf.d/56-emojione-color.conf.

Comment: That's it!  May I ask how you found it out?

Comment: I did some extreme brute force testing, i.e. moving my entire font config folder. This fixed the mathematica fonts (but predictably broke everything else). I remembered people complaining about emojione during an earlier google search for my problem. So I just deleted the config file and it seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I just came across this post pointing out the possibility of application-specific font config behaviour: https://github.com/eosrei/emojione-color-font/issues/51

I have added "Mathematica" specific exceptions both for the "Bitstream Vera Sans" and "sans-serif" to my 56-emojione-color.conf file and now I have both Mathematica displaying well and also emojis in my favourite applications.

Comment: KI am experiencing the exact issue with mathematica 8 on kde. Deleting the file is easy. Kindly guide me on adding the font exception as i could not understand the code. Do we have to "replace firefox" with "mathematica" in your suggested code.