# Alignement of text

Tags: output-formatting, grid-layouts, text, alignment

I adopted the following clever code from Mr. Wizard (see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31727/hold-expression-with-randominteger) ).

```
HoldForm[+##] & @@ RandomInteger[100, 2]
```

I want to prepare a practising table of addition for my son.

Something like:

```
Table[Text[
   Style[ToString[HoldForm[+##] & @@ RandomInteger[100, 2]] <> " = ", 
    Italic, 20]], {100}] // 
 Column[#, Left, Background -> {{LightGray, GrayLevel[.9]}}, 
   Frame -> True, ItemSize -> 10] &
```

However, I want the output to be "aligned".
If the four first elements of the output is, for instance, 12+5=, 3+48=, 78+89=, and 7+9= I want them to be aligned as follows

```
12 +  5  =
 3 + 48  =
78 + 89  =
 7 +  9  =
```

How is it possible to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: @Kuba. Thanks for properly modifying the tags.

Comment: dimitris, speaking of _practicing tables_  you might like [this q/a](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1864/125)

Comment: @ kguler. Wow! Thank you! I think my son will need less hour to finish the table than the time I will need to fully grasp the codes:-)!

Comment: I also think that the link below may be useful for relevant things. http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/inactive-objects/make-addition-and-multiplication-tables.html

Comment: BTW, all the examples of Inactivate I have seen so far is with for Built-in functions like Plus or Times. Is it a reason for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slightly more handy approach (unless you want to work with negative integers):

```
Grid[
 {#, "+", #2, "=", Item["", ItemSize -> 3]} & @@@ RandomInteger[20, {10, 2}]
 ,
 Alignment -> {{Right, Center, Right, Center, Center}},
 BaseStyle -> {Italic, 20},
 Frame -> True,
 Background -> {{}, {{GrayLevel@.9, GrayLevel@.95}}}
 ]
```

[image]

---

A simplistic first pass at adapting this for negative integers in the second column:

```
SeedRandom[1]
ints = RandomInteger[{-200, 200}, {10, 2}];

lines = {#, If[#2 < 0, "-", "+"], Abs@#2, "=", Spacer[50]} & @@@ ints;

Grid[lines,
 Alignment -> {{Right, Center, Right, Center, Center}}, 
 Frame -> True, 
 Background -> {{}, {{GrayLevel@.9, GrayLevel@.95}}}]
```

[image]

Note: I ran into [this problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55435/121) while exporting the image above; that is something you may wish to be aware of if you suddenly see excess quotation marks in your images.

Comment: Thank you very much! But, next scholar year, my son will indeed work with negative numbers:-)!

Comment: Kuba: certainly this method can be adapted for negative numbers; would you like me to edit your post to do that or include it in my own?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard sure if you want and have an idea, without clear specification I would waste half of a day thinking if  + (-10) or -10 and similar things.

Comment: I added a simple method.  Hopefully it works well enough to meet with your approval.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of using [`HoldForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldForm.html) and `Plus` is to allow automatic formatting rules for `Plus` to apply while preventing evaluation.  Since you want custom formatting rules that method may be inapplicable.

To get alignment we can either use a tabular format like `Grid` (as Kuba did) or we can pad the numbers themselves.  One automatic approach to the latter is [`PaddedForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PaddedForm.html):

```
SeedRandom[1]
ints = RandomInteger[{-200, 200}, {10, 2}];

PaddedForm[HoldForm[+##] == Spacer[1], 3] & @@@ ints // Column
```

[image]

Here I actually manged to keep `HoldForm[+##]` but you can see that the spacing is a little strange.  I also had to specify the maximum integer length.  If we try manual padding after converting to strings it will probably end up more complicated that just using `Grid`, although if padding with zeros is acceptable you may look at [`IntegerString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerString.html).

Comment: @ Mr Wizard: Thank you very much! (Superficially) simple things need sometimes a lot of thought and work:-)!